# How to print the directory tree in terminal

Tags: command-line

What is the command that can be used to draw the directory tree inside the terminal emulator?

[image]

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You can use `tree` to print the directory tree in terminal. Install `tree` from terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

To see the directory tree, use

```
tree /path/to/folder
```

Or navigate to a directory and just use

```
tree
```

It has some advanced options too. You can see owner's `username`, `groupname`, date of last modification of a file/folder and so on using `tree`. It supports directory colors of `ls` so you can see colourized outputs.

See `man tree` for more.

Comment: If you wish to tree only directories use `-d` switch.

Comment: clean and easy tool

Comment: or if you use brew on OSX. "brew install tree"

Comment: I was searching how to do it on Win7 + cmder : `tree` works well.

Comment: @AshHimself yep beat me to it. ;)

Comment: How can I save the output of tree command in an image file?

Comment: or 
brew install tree
note sudo isn't necessary and actually won't work.

Answer (score 75):

You can do it easily with the following command:

```
find . -type d | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/| - \1/"
```

This command will search recursively for directories inside the parent directory, and then draw the tree of the directories found.

You may also try the following to include all of the files as well.

```
find | sed 's|[^/]*/|- |g'
```

Comment: Please split and explain the above command for me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Buddy the overall of the command is clear if you wan to learn more about sed please refer to some tutorials or google it. It's really hard to explain all sed here!

Comment: Maythux, you're right that if you understand sed then your script is clear, but don't be fooled into thinking sed/regexes are anything but a cryptic language you've learned over the years.  It's hardly intuitive - which I think is the spirit of Avinash Raj's comment.

Comment: What would I need to change to ignore hidden directories?

Comment: how to leave a specific directory?

Answer (score 18):

There is a program called [`tree`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tree/) which lists directory content in a tree structure.

I think it's in the repositories (or even installed)

```
sudo apt install tree

tree -d /path/to/directory
```

Check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-directory-structure-command-line/) link for more.