# Show n files in each directory with tree command

Tags: command-line, tree

I have the following directory structure:

```
bocoup_data/
├── text_reuse
│   └── v2
│       └── json
│           ├── alignments
│           └── texts
└── topic_modelling
    └── v2
        └── json
```

I'd like to be able to show a subset of the files in those directories, because some of the directories pictured above have thousands of files. Is there a way to show only the first n files from each directory when calling the `tree` command in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

`tree` as such does not have any options for this, but you can prevent it from printing files for directories with more than `n` entries:

```
$ tree /usr --filelimit 10
/usr
├── bin [3260 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── include [1110 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── lib [3700 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── lib32 [610 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── lib64 -> lib
├── local
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── gpg1v -> /usr/bin/gpgv
│   │   └── vless
│   ├── etc
│   ├── games
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── man
│   ├── sbin
│   ├── share
│   │   └── man -> ../man
│   └── src
├── sbin -> bin
├── share [243 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
└── src

19 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Thanks @muru; this is close to what I am after, but I would like to show n files from those directories that have more than n files as well.

Comment: For anybody looking to display the directories only, use [`tree /usr -d`](https://askubuntu.com/a/431257/775359)

Answer (score 0):

The `find` shell command has options to limit output to files of certain max age only. This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked on [SU](https://superuser.com/q/840152/116475), and [glallen](https://superuser.com/users/19867/glallen) wrote a Python script for it since `tree` doesn't have the option:

---

> Usage: `tree.py -f [file limit] <directory>`
>
> If a number is specified for -f [file limit] then `... <additional files>` is printed and the other files are skipped. Additional
> directories should not be skipped however. If the file limit is set to
> 10000 (default) this acts as no limit
>
> ```py
> #! /usr/bin/env python
> # tree.py
> #
> # Written by Doug Dahms
> # modified by glallen @ StackExchange
> #
> # Prints the tree structure for the path specified on the command line
>
> from os import listdir, sep
> from os.path import abspath, basename, isdir
> from sys import argv
>
> def tree(dir, padding, print_files=False, limit=10000):
>     print padding[:-1] + '+-' + basename(abspath(dir)) + '/'
>     padding = padding + ' '
>     limit = int(limit)
>     files = []
>     if print_files:
>         files = listdir(dir)
>     else:
>         files = [x for x in listdir(dir) if isdir(dir + sep + x)]
>     count = 0
>     for file in files:
>         count += 1
>         path = dir + sep + file
>         if isdir(path):
>             print padding + '|'
>             if count == len(files):
>                 tree(path, padding + ' ', print_files, limit)
>             else:
>                 tree(path, padding + '|', print_files, limit)
>         else:
>             if limit == 10000:
>                 print padding + '|'
>                 print padding + '+-' + file
>                 continue
>             elif limit == 0:
>                 print padding + '|'
>                 print padding + '+-' + '... <additional files>'
>                 limit -= 1
>             elif limit <= 0:
>                 continue
>             else:
>                 print padding + '|'
>                 print padding + '+-' + file
>                 limit -= 1
>
> def usage():
>     return '''Usage: %s [-f] [file-listing-limit(int)] <PATH>
> Print tree structure of path specified.
> Options:
> -f          Print files as well as directories
> -f [limit]  Print files as well as directories up to number limit
> PATH        Path to process''' % basename(argv[0])
>
> def main():
>     if len(argv) == 1:
>         print usage()
>     elif len(argv) == 2:
>         # print just directories
>         path = argv[1]
>         if isdir(path):
>             tree(path, ' ')
>         else:
>             print 'ERROR: \'' + path + '\' is not a directory'
>     elif len(argv) == 3 and argv[1] == '-f':
>         # print directories and files
>         path = argv[2]
>         if isdir(path):
>             tree(path, ' ', True)
>         else:
>             print 'ERROR: \'' + path + '\' is not a directory'
>     elif len(argv) == 4 and argv[1] == '-f':
>         # print directories and files up to max
>         path = argv[3]
>         if isdir(path):
>             tree(path, ' ', True, argv[2])
>         else:
>             print 'ERROR: \'' + path + '\' is not a directory'
>     else:
>         print usage()
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()
> ```
>
> When run, it should produce output similar to:
>
> ```
> user@host /usr/share/doc $ python /tmp/recipe-217212-1.py -f 2 . | head -n 40
> +-doc/
>   |
>   +-libgnuradio-fft3.7.2.1/
>   | |
>   | +-copyright
>   | |
>   | +-changelog.Debian.gz
>   |
>   +-libqt4-script/
>   | |
>   | +-LGPL_EXCEPTION.txt
>   | |
>   | +-copyright
>   | |
>   | +-... <additional files>
>   |
>   +-xscreensaver-gl/
>   | |
>   | +-copyright
>   | |
>   | +-changelog.Debian.gz
>   | |
>   | +-... <additional files>
> ```